# How do I make armor stands upside down using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map where you ride around on a motorcycle. My first task in making the motorcycle was making a model using armorstands and ever since the problem occurred I've been using mcStacker and I've tried naming it Dinnerbone. No luck. I've been playing Armor do with the pose but I can only move the legs, arms, and head.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think this is really possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Dinnerbone or Grum names (I think Grum is correct. Haven't used it in a long time and I usually use Dinnerbone) are not supported by Armor Stands as I'm aware.

Although the Dinnerbone tag won't work, there is another solution, although it may not be what you're looking for. One thing you could try is setting all of the position NBT to 90 (Don't know the NBT tags right now, I'd have to pull them up).

Personally I wouldn't go this route, but here is a better route. Your best bet would be 4 invisible armor stands with armor in each slot (Helmet for Armor Stand 1, Chestplate for Armor Stand 2, etc) and then positioning them based on which armor piece they are equipped with. This could be tedious but for what you're looking for this would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and it's not possible, so I just used a skeleton wearing a coal block on his head instead of an armor stand. I also had an invisible armor stand wearing a iron leggings to make the front of the motorcycle, and it was pretty easy from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use specially placed minecarts positioned at different angles to achieve that. You can use /tp commands and probably make the minecart invisible. I have seen this logic implemented to create modless spheres. I myself am not sure how to do it, but you could google it...

Answer (score -3):

Use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). It works for putting anything in the position you want.

Comment: And how should someone use this to make it do what the asker wants?

Comment: MCEdit loads your world like you're in Minecraft. There are some utilities that you can use. There's one called "Fill" that replaces the block by another that you want, in the position you want.
An example: You put a normal armor stand in the game. Then, with MCEdit, there's a list of elements for replacing it, you choose the Armor Stand upside down. You press fill, you save, and that's all.
If you can't put it in the game, there's another option that is the brush. You choose the Armor Stand and how many, you click on the right point and there you have it.